# How to use pipe inside inside switchMap

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

This is the [original](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qhqpyw?file=index.ts) code.

```
import { map, switchMap, delay, tap, mapTo } from "rxjs/operators";
import { of, fromEvent } from "rxjs";
console.log("==================START=================");
const click1 = fromEvent(document.getElementById("click1"), "click");

const example = click1.pipe(
  mapTo("START"),
  tap(console.log),
  delay(2000),
  mapTo("yayyyy")
);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I have button. When the button is clicked several times quickly, I want to show only "yayy" once, 2 second after the last click.

Here is my attempt, yayy never shows up.

```
import { map, switchMap, delay, tap, mapTo } from "rxjs/operators";
import { of, fromEvent } from "rxjs";
console.log("==================START=================");
const click1 = fromEvent(document.getElementById("click1"), "click");

const example = click1.pipe(
  mapTo("START"),
  tap(console.log),
  switchMap(_ =>
    of().pipe(
      delay(2000),
      mapTo("yayyyy")
    )
  )
);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I have to use switchMap . ( I cannot use debounceTime or throtleTime)

Comment: `of()` doesn't emit any `next` notification and just completes. So you can use `of(null)` (or whatever value) and it'll emit one `next` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
switchMapTo(timer(2000).pipe(mapTo("yayyyy")))
```

should be about all you need.